# What is the MSIT Recommendad value for Application Insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want the MSIT Recommendad  value for Application Insight.
How i can find it.

I have searched it on microsoft website but i can't able to find it.

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by value?

Comment: values like recommended values like location,id,name

Comment: Changed my answer, take a look at that.

Comment: is there any source where i can find the values that are recommended by the microsoft while configuring any service on azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights is the service that can be added to your project through the Visual Studio or manually by adding it to the configuration files.
The tutorials are [available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/).

Regarding recommendations - there are not very many recommendations, you should select the region where your project are, to reduce the network latency. 
Name - one of the best practices is to use prefixes for your deployment, for example, "ws-northeu-instance1" and "ws-appins" or something like that.

Comment: From where i can get recommendations if any?

Comment: I had the experience of reading best practices from Microsoft only in that format - https://github.com/mspnp/performance-optimization/blob/master/Assessing-System-Performance-Against-KPI.md#insertlink# . I think there are no official guidance that are specific to the AppInsights except traditional things like i described.